# Does the SystemFolder property always transform its value depending on the Windows platform, i.e. x64 or x86?

Tags: windows, wix, wix3.8

I was trying to search a driver file in [SystemFolder]\drivers\ and I used the line below

```
<util:FileSearch Path="[SystemFolder]\drivers\my_Driver.sys" Result="exists" Variable="myDriver" />
```

The driver file that I am searching is always installed in C:\Windows\System32.
So, will using the SystemFolder property work even if I am installing on a x64 platform? Does the SystemFolder property transform its value based on the Windows platform being installed on?

Comment: On an x64 system you need System64Folder. Without knowing the architectures you support and if there are 32 and 64-bit versions of that driver I can't tell whether you will need an MSI for x86 and also one for x64.

Comment: After reviewing our product's drivers, I have found out that the both the 64 and 32 bit driver versions are always installed in C:\Windows\System32. I'll have to modify the drivers for this to work. Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372055.aspx) should answer your question entirely. Here's the excerpt:

> The installer sets this property. For example, on 32-bit Windows the
>   value may be C:\Windows\System32. On 64-bit Windows, the value may be
>   C:\Windows\SysWow64.

Comment: Oh okay. So this means I'll have to hard code my Path, i.e. C:\Windows\System32, when searching for the driver.

EDIT: After reviewing our product's drivers, it turns out our product's drivers always install to C:\Windows\System32. I'll just fix this and everything will be fine. Anyway, thanks for the link. ;)